# Fix width in Stack to width of first child

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I got a `Stack`-Widget with two childs. The first one is an image, the second one is text. I want to place the text on top of the image, hence the `Stack`. But when the text is quite long, the text overflows on the left and right. I want it to stay on the image. How can I limit the stacks width to the width of the image?

My Code:

```
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  children: [
    ExtendedImage.network(
      UserSession().currentImgURL!,
      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
      cache: true,
      cacheWidth: 1000,
      enableMemoryCache: false,
      enableLoadState: true,
    ),
    OutlinedText(
      text: Text(title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: kIsWeb ? 5.sp : 18.sp, height: 1.1)),
      strokes: [
        OutlinedTextStroke(color: Colors.black, width: 5),
      ],
    )
  ],
)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show your current result image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Positioned`

**Example**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  static MyAppState? of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.findAncestorStateOfType<MyAppState>();

  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final controller = TextEditingController(text: 'ABC');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Center(
          child: Stack(
//           fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: [
              Image.network(
                'https://i0.wp.com/static1.srcdn.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Among-Us-Random-Name-Generator.jpg?w=750&ssl=1',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                child: Text(
                  'bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: when doing that I get `The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.`

Comment: @progNewbie you may need to specify the size for the `Stack`, because the Stack will take the maximum possible size. Or using `IntrinsicHeight` wrap your `Stack`. im updated the answer

Comment: Actually this stretches my image

Comment: @progNewbie because the text need size to wrap and the stack size is expand by your text size but your image not. Then you need to specify size of stack to solve problem. About the image, use `fit: BoxFit.xxx` to adjust

Comment: @progNewbie okey, im update the answer againt